# Elixir Compile Error: definitions with multiple clauses and default values require a header

Tags: elixir

I'm getting "Elixir Compile Error: definitions with multiple clauses and default values require a header." For the following function. I'm not clear on why I'm getting this error exactly? Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

```
  def stream(query, opts \\ []) do
    initial_key = Keyword.get(opts, :initial_key, 0)
    key_name = Keyword.get(opts, :key_name, :id)
    chunk_size = Keyword.get(opts, :chunk_size, 500)

    Stream.resource(fn -> {query, initial_key} end,
      fn {query, last_seen_key} ->
        results = query
          |> Ecto.Query.where([r], field(r, ^key_name) > ^last_seen_key)
          |> Ecto.Query.limit(^chunk_size) 
          |> __ENV__.module.all

        case List.last(results) do
          %{^key_name => last_key} ->
            {results, {query, last_key}}
          nil ->
            {:halt, {query, last_seen_key}}
        end
      end,
      fn _ -> [] end)
  end
```

Error Message:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/peanutbutter/repo.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/peanutbutter/repo.ex:3: definitions with multiple clauses and default values require a header. Instead of:

    def foo(:first_clause, b \\ :default) do ... end
    def foo(:second_clause, b) do ... end

one should write:

    def foo(a, b \\ :default)
    def foo(:first_clause, b) do ... end
    def foo(:second_clause, b) do ... end

def stream/2 has multiple clauses and defines defaults in one or more clauses
    lib/peanutbutter/repo.ex:3: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Comment: Do you have another definition of `stream` function somewhere above or below this?

Comment: I can't find another definition of stream

Comment: Which line exactly throws this error? Can you post the complete error message including the stacktrace?

Comment: Line 3 in repo.ex simply loads the file with the stream function in it

Comment: Ecto already defines a function called `stream/2` when you `use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :my_app`.

Comment: Does that mean I should rename my `stream` function?

Comment: Yes. (SO comments have a minimum length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ecto already defines a function called `stream/2` when you `use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :my_app`. You are going to need to call your function something else.